# How to get correct timezone id of current session

Tags: postgresql

On my local machine have CET timezone (postgres config same), when i run request `SELECT current_setting('TIMEZONE')` from java i get 'GMT-1' which is incorrect. I cant use that id in java. How to get from postgresql 'GMT+1' instead?
Is there command to get ISO timezone name/id?

Comment: Related: [Oddities with AT TIME ZONE and UTC offsets](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/160065/2037)

Comment: It will return the setting you have saved or saved by default. To get the desired value you have to set the value first.

Comment: "[Posix style timezone names beginning with "Etc/GMT" have their sign reversed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database) from the standard ISO 8601 convention. In the "Etc" area, zones west of GMT have a positive sign and those east have a negative sign in their name (e.g "Etc/GMT-14" is 14 hours ahead of GMT.)"

Comment: Therefore `GMT-1` corresponds to an offset of `+1`, which is currently in agreement with `CET`. In other words, Postgresql is conforming with Posix style timezone names when it returns `GMT-1`.

Comment: JBCD Driver give me 'GMT-1' not 'Etc/GMT-1' so should simple use replace in java to revert sign? Or is command in postgres to do it?